# Should unprocessed features be kept in the dataset along engineered ones?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I'm working on a Machine Learning classification problem that has five *Service Spending* features (among many others) in its dataset, each sample is a customer. For instance, here are the first three customers for these features:

| Service 1 | Service 2 | Service 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 156 | 0 | 0 |
| 564 | 42 | 0 |
| 0 | 100 | 140 |

I've used these numerical features to create a new set where I bin them into 5 categories, according to the spending amount. This gives me an idea of how each customer could be categorized, according to their spending. Something like this:

| Service 1 - Cat | Service 2 - Cat | Service 3 - Cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 3 |

**Question**: Now that I have engineered these new features, should I keep the original, unprocessed ones, and pass them along the new ones to the classifier or should I feed the classifier only the new features?